# Convertir un String en ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> en Java

Tags: java, arraylist

Estoy intentando convertir una cadena en una arreglo bidimensional, Es decir tengo lo siguiente fragmento de codigo:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> bidimensional;
String cadena = "[Carlos,Estudiante,Medicina],[Karla, Maestra,Psicologia]";
bidimensional = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>(Arrays.asList(cadena.split(',')));
```

Pero Me sale Error

```
constructor ArrayList.ArrayList(int) is not aplicable
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En primer lugar vale aclarar que una lista de listas no es un array bidimensional. Lo digo por el nombre de la variable. Aunque tal vez no sea lo que estabas pensando. Dicho eso, no estás teniendo en cuenta que tu cadena tiene corchetes y comas como separadores de la lista de personas (por decirlo de alguna manera) y la lista de atributos (nombre, rol, carrera).

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final String cadena = "[Carlos,Estudiante,Medicina],[Karla,Maestra,Psicologia]";
    final String[] filas = cadena.substring(1, cadena.length() - 1).split("\\],\\[");
    List<List<String>> bidimensional = new ArrayList<>(filas.length);
    for (String fila : filas) {
        List<String> entrada = Arrays.asList(fila.split(","));
        bidimensional.add(entrada);
    }
    System.out.println(bidimensional);
}
```

En primer lugar dividimos la lista en función del separado más externo, que serían los corchetes. Por simplicidad eliminamos el primer y último caracter ya que serán los corchetes de apertura y cierre. Y usanmos `],[` como separador porque es lo que hay justo entre dos personas. Una vez que tenemos el array de filas creamos la lista principal inicializada con el número de item del array. Luego por cada elemento del array volvemos a dividir la cadena pero usando la coma. Esto nos va a dar una lista de tres elementos que directamente la podemos agregar como elemento de la lista más externa.

Es importante que uses la interfaz List para las variables así pueden ser independientes de la implementación que elijas.

Comment: gracias, me funciono :)